# why isnt working my function to concatenate?

Tags: c++

I've tried so many times in different way to concatenate two strings, one way gives me segment fail,and the other way don't give me error but not it's making the correct function of concatenate. I need result is like this aa, what am I doing wrong?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
char str1[20], str2[20], str3[20];
void stringConcat(char[], char[], char[]);
void stringConcat(char str1[], char str2[], char str3[])
{
    int i = 0, j = 0;
    if (str1[i] != '\0') {
        str3[i] = str1[i];
        i++;
    }
    if (str2[j] != '\0') {
        str3[i + j] = str2[j];
        j++;
    }

    str3[i] = '\0';
}
int main()
{
    int compare;

    cout << "First string" << endl;
    cin >> str1;

    cout << "Second string" << endl;
    cin >> str2;
    stringConcat(str1, str2, str3);
    cout << "result: " << str3 << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why do you think it should work?

Comment: 1) What did you do? (you answered this already). 2) What did you expect to happen? 3) What happened?

Comment: thanks so much man

Comment: it lack to sum the other index

Comment: Did you try [explaining your code to your rubber duck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging)?

Comment: How can you concatenate 2 arrays of 20 to one array of length 30?  I believe the result array should have a capacity of 40.